# How does a Hardcoded number in php turns to another number in my database ? Strange

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, localhost

I got some mysterious bug ..

Okay so I'm working in LocalHost with The latest version on MySQL. I'm working with CodeIgniter (2.0.2)
I'm trying to implement a function like that in a model :

```
function saveMyFriends($friends_list){

$this->load->library('encrypt');    
    foreach($friends_list as $friend){
        // echo $friend['id'].' : '.utf8_decode($friend['name']).'</br>';

        $query_str ="INSERT INTO sc_friends (fb_id, fb_friends_id, fb_friends_name) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)";
        $fb_id =$this->session->userdata('user_fbid');
        $this->db->query($query_str, array($fb_id, $friend['id'], sha1(utf8_decode($friend['name']))));
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Which is supposed to save in a database my list of Facebook friends but it happens that around 5% of the results have the same Fb_id ... Which is impossible. So I've tried to enter some friends manually, I just changed`enter code here` few lines :

```
    function saveMyTwoFriends(){

$this->load->library('encrypt');    
        $query_str ="INSERT INTO sc_friends (fb_id, fb_friends_id, fb_friends_name) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)";
        $this->db->query($query_str, array(7518777XX, 1000028691344XX, sha1(utf8_decode('XXX XXXX'))));
    return TRUE;
}
```

(Of course, X is either a real number or a Real Name)
But once again , in my database, when I entered the third one manually (the one I give you here in example) I had the recurring "same id" : "2147483647"

How is that possible ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2147483647 is the biggest integer representable in 32-bit PHP. If your database library tries to treat bigger number like 100002869134477 as integer - what you get is 2147483647. You may use floats or constant strings or extensions like bcmath or gmp is you need to work with larger numbers.

Comment: Not as separate type. On 64-bit systems, when PHP is compiled as 64-bit binary, its integer type is 64-bit, but on 32-bit systems 32 bits is what you get from the integer type.

Comment: Okay, Thanks !
What about using BigInt ? What is that Signature problem in using BigInt ?

Comment: @MilesM. you could use gmp or bcmath modules to work with longer numbers if you need to. However I don't know what you DB library is, so this may not work. You may also store these values as strings, not integers.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook always defines / returns user facebook id as a `string` so I would use `varchar()` in your database instead of `bigint()`

> id - The user's Facebook ID. `string`.